Finding a convergent subnet
In Bekka, de la Harpe and Valette 's book on Property (T), there is a lemma whose proof has some parts that are a bit hard for me to understand. We work with a locally compact group $G$ and $\hat G$, the irreducible unitary representations of $G$. We fix $\pi_0$, a finite dimensional
irreducible unitary representation of $G$. Suppose we have a net $(\phi_i)_{i\in I}$ of convex combinations of normalised functions of positive type associated to irreducible unitary representations in $\hat G$ which converges to $\phi$ in the weak* topology on $L^\infty(G)$. It is claimed that we can write $\phi_i = a_i\psi_i + b_i\psi_i '$, where $\psi_i$ is a convex combination of normalised functions of positive type associated to irreducible representations in $\hat G - \{\pi_0\}$, $ \psi_i'$ is a convex combination of normalised functions of positive type associated to $\{\pi_0\}$, $a_i, b_i$ are real numbers in $[0,1]$ and $a_i + b_i = 1$. I have tried some manipulations but they aren't taking me anywhere. Is this a simple calculation or do we need some theorem? $$\\$$
Suppose that the above claim is true, then it is also claimed that there is a subnet such that $\psi_i$ converges to $\psi$ and $ \psi_i'$ converges to $ \psi'$, where $ \psi$ is a convex combination of normalised functions of positive type  and $ \psi'$ is also a convex combination of normalised functions of positive type. I am clueless regarding how one may show the existence of such a subnet.
